# Can a web service get a custom error message from a web service on a different server?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a web service running on server A that returns a custom error message in a Java ResponseEntity object like this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>("My custom error message.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

I have another web service running on server B that calls the web service on server A but instead of "My custom error message", I get the following:

> can't parse JSON.  Raw result:
>   Server returned HTTP response code: 400

If I call the web service on server A directly, then I get an error 400 with "My custom error message" as expected.

I've isolated the problem to when server B tries to read the response from server A.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
```

When server B receives the error 400 from server A, conn.getInputStream() throws an IOException which is caught but the "My custom error message" is lost in the exception.

```
catch (IOException e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Is it possible for server B to return the custom error message from server A?  How can it be done?

I am using Java 8, Spring Boot 2.0.2, Tomcat 9, and Swagger UI 2.8 to test the web services.

UPDATE: If server A returns code 200 instead of 400, then IOException isn't thrown on server B.  A JsonParseException is thrown instead and server B returns "My custom error message".

Comment: If server B is expecting JSON, try adding quotation marks to your string value.

Comment: That removes the "can't parse JSON. Raw result:" part but the client still wouldn't know why the server returned with HTTP error 400.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this is happening is that your exception though is getting thrown correctly from A is handled inside `conn.getInputStream` which sees the BAD_REQUEST exception.
One possible solution i can guess is that you somehow check before making the object of input stream reader check weather connection is throwing some exception or not.

```
try{
    conn.open();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream()));
    }catch(Exception e){
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

A method similar to conn.open should throw your custom exception before making input stream reader's object

Comment: I could have server B check the contents of the body before it sends the request to server A but server A already checks the content that it receives.  I'd like to avoid duplicate code on both servers but it seems unavoidable.